# How to increase rectangle size in barcode android

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am working on a barcode scanner in which the red line and rectangle look small and visible at corner. How can I draw the red line int the center of the rectangle frame similar to this link?

http://blog.digitaltinder.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/BarcodeScanner_thumb.png

What I am getting is:

[image]
My code is as follows

```
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(BarcodeScan.this);
scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {     
    IntentResult scanningResult =IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        //get content from Intent Result
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        //get format name of data scanned
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), scanContent+scanFormat,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to integrate with Barcode Scanner by Intent, but have somehow created your own messed up version of the app. You can't do both.